# Kotlin: conditional items during map creation

Tags: syntax, kotlin

Is there a way to do something like this in Kotlin?

```
mapOf(
   "key1" to var1,
   "key2" to var2,
   if(var3 > 5) "key3" to var3       
)
```

Or the only way is to add the key "key3" after the map is created?
I'd like to add an item to a map only if some condition is met.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

One way to do that is to use [`listOfNotNull(...)`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/list-of-not-null.html) + [`.toMap()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/to-map.html) and put `null`s where you want to skip an item:

```
val map = listOfNotNull(
   "key1" to var1,
   "key2" to var2,
   if (var3 > 5) "key3" to var3 else null
).toMap()
```

You can additionally use [`.takeIf { ... }`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/take-if.html), but note that it will evaluate the pair regardless of the condition, so if the pair expression calls a function, it will be called anyway:

```
val map = listOfNotNull(
    /* ... */
    ("key3" to var3).takeIf { var3 > 5 }
).toMap()
```

Comment: Nice! I didn't know of the `listOfNotNull`-function. I started writing an answer with an array that I filtered for nulls and then spread for the vararg parameter, but this is much cleaner.

Comment: This is short and clean, I like it, but isn't there an overhead due to filtering and converting to map?

Comment: Converting to map takes the same time as in `mapOf` (the `vararg` of pairs is processed in the same way as the list above is). There is, of course, some overhead for filtering as it copies the collection. However, if there's not many pairs, there should not be much overhead due to good locality of reference. Though I would not do that in performance-critical parts of code (those running thousands times over a short period of time), instead adding such pairs after the map creation. I think the best way to learn how the performance is affected in your specific case is to benchmark your code.

Comment: OK, I am going to accept this as correct answer, because the code seems more clear and readable. Thanks :)

Answer (score 24):

**Update:** Kotlin 1.6 introduced a map builder ([`buildMap`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/build-map.html)). You can use it like this:

```
val map = buildMap<Char, Int>() {
   put('a', 1)
   put('b', 2)
   if(var3 > 5) { put('c', 3) }
}
```

---

You can use the [spread operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#variable-number-of-arguments-varargs) `*` to do that:

```
val map = mapOf(
   "key1" to var1,
   "key2" to var2,
   *(if(var3 > 5) arrayOf("key3" to var3) else arrayOf())       
)
```

Answer (score -1):

I like to use a "builder"

```
val map = let {
    val m = HashMap<String, Int>() //use a mutable map as a map builder
    m["key1"] = var1
    m["key2"] = var2
    if(var3 > 5){ m["key3"] = var3 }
    m.toMap()
} //wrapped in a lambda so the builder is inside a private scope and can't accidentally be used
```